# How to backshift epistemic 'would'

Tags: modal-verbs, backshifting

> Katia asks John to tell her whatever he knows about her father. John
>   responds with Litvenko's age, medical condition (rheumatoid arthritis)
>   and that he speaks several different languages - including Tamil. He
>   also says that he has stage 3 lung cancer. With these facts, Katia
>   figures out that her dad **would be living** in a country which has a warm
>   climate where orchids can grow, moreover with advanced medical
>   treatments available.
>
> Source: [*Hitman: Agent 47*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman:_Agent_47)

I think the bolded **would** is epistemic, signifying a higher possibility than **could/might**, but less sure than **will**.

The question is how to backshift it. I think it would be:

> Katia figured out that her dad **would have been living** in a country which had a warm climate where orchids could grow...

But this backshift could bring an ambiguity with it.

Consider this:

> Katia figures out that her dad **will have been living** in a country
>   which had a warm climate where orchids could grow...

If we backshift it, I think it would be the same as the former.

Did I get it right?

Comment: I suppose some speakers in some contexts might feel that ***would*** is  "less sure" than ***will***, but in most contexts such a fine distinction would be neither intended nor understood. But note that *I thought it would be true* usually implies that the speaker now ***knows*** it's true, whereas *I thought it would have been true* usually implies the speaker now knows it's ***not*** true.

Comment: As TRomano suggested, "would have been true" could be epistemic and factual as well. We could roughly paraphrase it as "it is very likely that sth was/has been true". I got confused.  I think TRomano would have been right about it. Perhaps it'll turn out he *was* right! :) @FumbleFingers

Comment: After reading all your comments, I think you are saying the OP's example sounds unnatural to your ears. Perhaps that's because Wikipedia is re-edited by people who speak different dialects. I think "will be living" would be more apt here. What's your take on it? @FumbleFingers

Comment: The potential nuance of difference between *[will or would] **be / have been** living* is that the perfective form *(have been)* more explicitly focuses on the more extended (including *past*, rather than just *present*) period during which her dad has living in some speculated location. In context, this might be more relevant if Katia was wondering whether her father might be particularly sun-tanned, say (if and when she actually meets him), whereas *will/would **be living*** might work better if she's wondering whether *right now* he's sitting huddled over a warming fire, perhaps.

Comment: Would "With these facts, Katia figures out that her dad would **LIVE** in a country.." fit in this context as well? Your answer will be very important to me. I have found a very interesting linguistic paper relevant to my issue here: *A pragmatic analysis of the epistemic would construction in English* https://books.google.com/books?isbn=3110176866  @FumbleFingers You might want to take a look. You could read all except one page which I don't think matters too much. :)

Comment: I should point out that it seems to me you're in danger of "over-thinking" what factors influence the average native speaker's choice of verb forms, and of assuming English has levels of precision which in practice simply don't exist. Bear in mind the Wikipedia page under scrutiny is already slightly "odd" because it's almost entirely written in *present* tense - tracking the progress of the narrative focus, rather than describing *events that happened*.

Comment: "Katia shows him her map of clues to **finding her father**. Katia asks John to tell her whatever he knows about her father." makes her father's whereabouts a salient open proposition. She instantiates the variable with a discrete member of contextually salient set: Singapore. @FumbleFingers

Comment: I agree with your assessment. Perhap it's just out of curiosity. The funny thing is that there are some people who share the same interest with me, like the authors of that paper I cited. :) @FumbleFingers

Comment: The authors of that paper are probably interested in linguistic analysis of factors which might influence native speaker choices. They're almost certainly *not* interested in identifying patterns which might help non-native speakers *learn* English. And note that there is no underlying "perfect, logical, fully-defined" version of English in the first place, even *conceptually*. It's not like, say, quantum theory (which can give accurate predictions, but even *that* isn't thought to truly represent whatever *really* underpins reality).

Comment: Yes, their main purpose is to examine a previously ignored usage of "would". The paper is very convincing and thought-provoking. I think it helps to gain a better understanding of when this particular use occurs and how it is different from other uses. :) @FumbleFingers

Comment: BTW, there's s disagreement between native speakers over this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73855 Peter Shor is very competent at linguistics. I agree with him that both *could* and *could have* are acceptable in English there. I just don't see why user21820 dislikes "could have" in the cited context. His answer strikes me as a strict rule, not a flexible choice. And he got three upvotes. I don't know who is right about it. @FumbleFingers

Comment: In *my* opinion, Peter is quite right that in your linked context, *...but then he **could have ordered** me* is "slightly better" in the strict grammatical sense. Simply because it "correctly" replicates the tense/modality of the prior context *(could have broken)*. But since native speakers tend to avoid *repeated* use of perfect and/or continuous forms where possible, so I suspect that *in practice* the simpler form *he **could order** me* would actually be preferred by most for the exact context.

Comment: ...bear in mind that in that exact context, if Zelazny *had* used the perfective form for *could have ordered*, he'd have had to do it again with *few people **would have enjoyed** doing...*, by which time the entire sentence would start to become weighed down with pointlessly convoluted verb forms, detracting from readability. In my preceding sentence I've unnecessarily complicated things by using *he'd have had to* rather than the simpler *he'd have to*. Which is fine now and then - but if you make a habit of it, the style becomes "stilted".

Comment: That was a very insightful point! It reminds me of the Grice's maxims. :) @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Katia is trying to figure out, from clues which are not stale, where her father is likely to be living now, then **would** is the correct verb.

**Katia figures out that her dad *would be living* in a country which has a warm climate... [etc]**

If she is trying to figure out, from *stale* clues, where her father is likely to have been living when the clues were fresh, then we would say:

**Katia figures out that her dad *would have been living* in a country which has a warm climate... [etc]**

You are correct.

But if Katia is trying to *guess*, from clues whose freshness or staleness is unknown, where her father is likely to have been living or to be living, then we would say:

**Katia guesses that, when they find her dad, he will have been living in a country which has a warm climate... [etc]**

Comment: I doubt there would be consistent agreement among native speakers on these matters, but personally I don't agree with the usage in your first scenario. For present tense speculation, *I think my dead cat **would** be living in cat heaven* sounds rather strange/circumlocutory to me. I'd be much more likely to say *I think my dead cat **will** be living in cat heaven* (past tense ***would*** pairs with past tense *I **thought...***)

Comment: The verb that invites the backshifting here is "figure out" (like *suppose, guess, conclude, figure, reckon, surmise, conjecture, ...* etc).  Does your "ear" feel the same if you change that sentence about your cat to use "suppose" instead of "think"? What happens if you also tack onto the end of the sentence "if he hadn't been such an alley-cat here on Earth"?

Comment: I don't think it would make any difference to me which specific *verb* was involved. But obviously if we tack on an ***if-clause***, the whole nature of the surmise changes. We're no longer talking about where I think my cat ***is***, but where I think he ***would*** be ***if*** the situation were different.

Comment: RIght, I was using that if-clause just to get a baseline to make sure your ear wasn't broken. :)  I grant that some speakers might feel no  inclination to backshift with this class of verb.  But for those who do backshift, a sentence like "From those clues, I reckon my dad *would be living* in a warm climate..." is natural, because while it is not a counterfactual statement, neither is it a simple statement of fact.  If I changed "I suppose" to "I am willing to bet", then I''d find "will be living" natural.

Comment: It might be interesting to raise this issue on ELU, but I really don't think the average *learner* stands to gain much by poring over the possibilities. My gut feel is that "backshifting", say, *Considering how long it's been out of the fridge, I think this fish **would be** putrid* simply doesn't work (we don't yet *know* if it's rotten, but whether it is or not, what we *will* discover is it's *current* state).

Comment: ...on the other hand, *Considering how long it's been out of the fridge, I think this fish **would be unsafe to eat*** is at least "acceptable" to me (although unnecessarily "wordy"). The difference in my second example being that we're not necessarily going to *eat* the fish anyway, so *that's* where the "hypothetical, irrealis" element comes in. But I'd still prefer the simpler tense even there.

Comment: The fish is cooked by now, considering how long it has been in the oven. Is the fish done? It's been in the oven for 10 minutes.  -- I suppose the fish would be cooked by now, considering it wasn't a very thick piece.

Comment: I'm afraid *I suppose it would be ready by now* doesn't really work for me. But it wouldn't be any better with *...ready **soon***, so maybe my point about the "current" state of the fish doesn't exactly nail it. Consider also what happens if we change the verb as well: [*I **hope** it will be ready soon*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hope+it+will+be+ready+soon%22) gets 106 hits in Google Books, but there are none at all for the corresponding *I hope it **would** be ready soon*.

Comment: Of course, increasing numbers of native speakers would go for the even simpler *present* tense with "hope" - *I hope **it's** ready soon!* But that doesn't work very well with *I think/suppose it's ready soon*, so maybe the particular verb is significant.

Comment: I've [raised this on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293712/que-sera-seria-what-will-be-would-be)

Comment: Come to think of it, would "With these facts, Katia figures out that her dad would **live** in a country.." fit in this context as well? Your answer will be very important to me. I have found a linguistic paper relevant to my issue here. @TRomano

Comment: The choice of tense will be contextual and reveal the speaker's attitude towards the implicit conclusion being drawn from the known facts. The *be living*..." form expresses the idea that the known facts support the view that he could have *survived* only in such a place, given his stage 3 lung cancer, whereas simple "would live" conveys the idea that he would have *chosen* such a place in which to settle down, given his illness, and is agnostic with regard to the question of whether he is still alive.

Comment: Makes sense! Does it sound natural to say "John left America two years ago. He would be living in Mexico now." (because he once told me Mexico was his favorite country)"  or  "John left America two years ago. He would have been living in Mexico since then. (The same reason)? @TRomano

Comment: "would be living in Mexico now" is fine.  But **would have been living in Mexico since then** has aspect issues for me: "since then" extends the time reference to the present but "would have been living" makes it a conjecture about the past. I'd expect "*will* have been living in Mexico since then."

Comment: That's great! One problem solved! Thanks to you! And is the *ing*-form obligatory when "would" is employed to express a conjection about the present or the past? Without the *ing*-form, would it always be interpreted as an irrealis reading, as in "He would have lived in Mexico, but ran out of cash. As a result, he gave it up"? @TRomano

Comment: Always is a place we never go. The weather there is cold, there's lots of snow. The dauntless in their parkas may welcome its extremes, but the cautious, the unbold, prefer "typically", it seems.

Comment: You should write poetry, really! Perhaps you do. :) You only answered my second question. So is the *ing*-form obligatory when "would" is employed to express a conjection about the present or the past? @TRomano

Comment: Knowing how much Kinzle B likes chocolate, I bet he would have eaten those cupcakes *as soon as he saw them sitting on the table*.... will have eaten those cupcakes *by now* .... will be eating those cupcakes *when we get to his house* ... would have eaten those cupcakes *even if they were too salty*.

Comment: ...would eat those cupcakes *even if they are too salty*.

Comment: Considering how good these examples are, I bet TRomano would have spent lots of time on great works of literature. .. will have spent lots of time on them by now. :) @TRomano

Comment: Or reading *101 Ways to Use Chocolate Chips*.

Comment: Change the verb from *bet* to *suppose* or *guess* and "will" becomes "would" (for me):  I guess he would have eaten them by now.  The choice between *will* or *would* reflects the degree of confidence.

Comment: By saying "I guess he would have eaten them by now," is there also a tense issue, as in the above "..would have been living in Mexico since then.."?

Comment: **I bet** and **I guess** are both present tense, so the shift from **will** to **would** in the dependent clause reflects the speaker's attitude towards its predication.

Answer (score 4):

I looked up Quirk et al.'s [Comprehensive Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), and it says (Unit 14.34):

> If a modal auxiliary in the direct speech is already in the past tense form, 
>   then the same form remains in the indirect speech.
>
> - "When I was in college I **would** study till two or three in the morning,' she recalled.
> - She recalled that when she (was/had been) in college she **would** study till two or three in the morning.

According to the book, "the modal auxiliary (**would**) has past time  reference in the  direct speech, and therefore backshift entails changing to the perfective (**would have studied**)."

Naturally, changing it to the perfective either in Quirk's or in your example would change the meaning to "counterfactual" (**would have been living** means he did not in reality live there). So I guess the answer is "no". We should leave **would** in its preterit form.

> Katia figured out that her dad **would be living** in a country which had a warm climate where orchids could grow...

---

As regards your concern concerning the backshifting of **will have been living**..

Since Future Perfect Continuous indicates duration before some point in the future, such a sentence would contain an expression that would make the meaning clear even with backshifting to **would have been living**:

> Katia figures out that her dad **will have been living** in a country which has a warm climate *for 10 years before she will be able to discover him*.

Backshifting:

> Katia figured out that her dad **would have been living** in a country which had a warm climate *for 10 years before she would be able to discover him*.